# Xamarin.Forms iOS statusbar color with NavigationPage

Tags: ios, statusbar, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I am building an application in Xamarin.Forms, on the iOS app I want the status bar color to be white. Here is what I have so far:

**App.cs**

```
public App()
{
    NavigationPage _navigationPage = new NavigationPage(new RootPage());

    MainPage = _navigationPage;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After a recent Xamarin update you are now able to do this by setting the BarTextColorProperty,

`_navigationPage.SetValue(NavigationPage.BarTextColorProperty, Color.White);`

However just like in [pvnak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32512897/3571997) you still need to add the following to your Info.plist

- Property: `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`
- Type: `boolean`
- Value: `No`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using a custom renderer, you can set the status bar color globally with this approach:

**Add the following property and value in your info.plist:**

- Property: `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance`
- Type: `boolean`
- Value: `No`

**Update the `AppDelegate.cs` in the iOS project with this line of code:**

```
UIApplication.SharedApplication.SetStatusBarStyle (UIStatusBarStyle.LightContent, false);
```

Comment: Deprecated in iOS 9

Comment: Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Or you do everything in info.plist: `<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
  <false/>
  <key>UIStatusBarStyle</key>
  <string>UIStatusBarStyleLightContent</string>`

Answer (score 0):

globaly change status bar text color and background color for ios

in App.xaml.cs:

```
var page = new NavigationPage(new MainPage()) { BarTextColor = Color.White };
```

in Info.plist:

```
<key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
          <false/>
```

and changing background color
in AppDelegate.cs => override bool FinishedLaunching(...):

```
var statusBar = UIApplication.SharedApplication.ValueForKey(new NSString("statusBar")) as UIView;
     if (statusBar.RespondsToSelector(new ObjCRuntime.Selector("setBackgroundColor:")))
     {
         statusBar.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
     }
```

and set padding top = 20 on every page